# Seeing scons file like python file in vim. File dependent properties

Tags: vim

I know I can `setf python` and then the file is recognized as python.
However I must redo this everytime I reload the scons file.

I have read some weeks ago that one could write in the last lines of a file with a special syntax and sets parameters that vim should read.

In my case I would like `setf python` to be set anytime I open this scons file.

However I don't remember the syntax, and I can't manage to find the web site where I read it was possible to have file dependent properties.

`#:setf python` on the last line doesn't seem to suffice.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39856146/how-to-make-vim-high-light-as-python-when-editing-scons-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct syntax:

```
# vim: set filetype=python:
```

But you need `set modeline` (it's default in my case) in .vimrc.

Read this [wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Modeline_magic) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

If the *scons* file always has the same name / adheres to a certain pattern, you can also configure the filetype detection; put the following into your `~/.vimrc`:

```
:autocmd BufNew,BufRead SConstruct setf python
```